# How to make it possible to add my Library on GitHub to Android Gradle Files?

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project hosted on GitHub at https://github.com/BoardiesITSolutions/NavigationDrawerManager.

I've seen some projects on GitHub state adding it to their gradle file in Android Studio to the dependencies section but this doesn't seem to be working for me.

I have tried compile: 'com.github.boardiesitsolutions.NavigationDrawerManager:+' but it keeps saying it can't find it, I've also tried replacing the + with the version number but no luck, Android Studio keeps saying it can't find it. I've added the repository MavenCentral as well.

Is there something I need to do from GitHub to make it accessible for Gradle?

Comment: Did you upload your artifacts to the Maven Central??

Comment: @Android777 already said it. Use `Jitpack.io` and let it do it for you :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see it on maven.
You can use this [website](https://jitpack.io/) to use non-mavenized libraries with Gradle.

Just add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to `repositories` section of `build.gradle` and use `compile 'com.github.BoardiesITSolutions:NavigationDrawerManager:0b14c84445'` in `dependencies`.